# Retrieve a list of files from online OneDrive folder and open them in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive

I am working on a project for a client who wants to map documents from 'OneDrive For Business', a web-based SharePoint, to Excel. The goal is to be able to retrieve the files from the shared location and list the file names on Excel, with the ability to open them in Adobe (through hyperlink I am assuming?).

It is also difficult to understand how to retrieve 180+ PDF documents from this folder, because they break into different viewable pages.

The folder will be continuously updated so being able to retrieve all the PDFs in that folder is important for my time-sensitive analysis.

I can share previous code that I created that pulled the same PDF documents from a static local drive... Please let me know if this is doable.

Answer (score -1):

For my personal uses, I've got something similar that I made work by having my OneDrive for business account sync the relevant folder to my computer and then treating it like a local drive.

I've got a macro that sounds similar to yours that allows recursively looping through any given mapped drive for the same goal, but it does have to be a mapped drive as it relies on some deep windows voodoo I pulled from an answer here on stack overflow a long time ago.